# Using AWS CLI to stop all instances in a region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, aws-sdk, aws-cli

How can I use the AWS CLI to stop every EC2 instance in a region (1 VPC)?

I did see an old thread saying that this should work:

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids $(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=pending,running" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]" --output text | tr '\n' ' ')
```

However, I get the following error when using the above command:

> Unknown options: --filters, Name=instance-state-name,Values=pending,running

Comment: past the actual command you are using + the version of aws-cli you have. Lookin at the docs, you'll see that `--filters` is valid: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

Comment: This exact command works for me. Does running just the nested portion  `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=pending,running" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]" --output text | tr '\n' ' '` work for you?